# How to show time difference between unix timestamp and current date in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, unix, timestamp, momentjs

I am using moment.js plugin to show updated times for entries in my application. All of the entries have a time_updated property in unix timestamp format. How can I take this time format and compare it to the current time. I have looked through the documentation and found this:

```
moment([2015, 0, 29]).fromNow()
```

But no where does it explain what the numbers between the brackets mean or what format should the parameters be in.

Below is the code I am working with

```
var timestamp = clientObject.topics_projects[x].date_updated;
var then = moment.unix(timestamp).format("HH:mm");
var now = moment(currentDate).format("HH:mm");
```

So how can I get the time difference between then and now? For example to read, "a few seconds ago" or "3 minutes ago."

Answer (score 7):

Your answer is already in your code. Moment is chainable, so:

```
var diff = moment.unix(timestamp).from(currentDate);
```

Or if `currentDate` is actually the current date, simply:

```
var diff = moment.unix(timestamp).fromNow();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the various `moment` constructor formats for the meaning of `moment([2015, 0, 29])` (specifically the [`Array[]` one](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/)).

For your specific question,

```
moment(something).fromNow()
```

where `something` can be a variety of things, including a timestamp, a date object, the abovementioned array of time quantities, and much more.